# CSS spinner styling

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Can some one enhance my spinner. i want one end to thicker and the other end to to be thin. i tried something but it did not work.

```
<div id="data-loader">
      <div class="loader">
          <div class="blue"></div>
      </div>
  </div>


#data-loader{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
.loader {
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: -30px 0 0 -30px;
    border-radius:50%;
}

.loader .blue {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    border-top:4px solid #7199C1;
    border-right:3px solid #7199C1;
    border-bottom:1px solid #7199C1;
    border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: spinner;
    -moz-animation-name: spinner;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinner
{
    from{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes spinner
{
    from{-moz-transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to{-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

I gave borders on top, right and bottom for a div. and a border-radius of 50%,

http://plnkr.co/edit/UKJZzDsDyfHxknRu12ZP?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never answered here but try to put your `border-left: 4px solid transparent`.

Put your `border-top` as `4px solid #color`. If you want more thickness on the end, put `10px` on `border-left` and `border-top`.

Answer (score 0):

If the effect you want is the effect I think you want, you were so, so close.

By changing these three figures, the animation is thicker at the start and tails off to the end.

`border-top:3px solid #7199C1;`
`border-right:6px solid #7199C1;`
`border-bottom:6px solid transparent;`